# Localhost wont open (Node.js server)

Tags: node.js, express

I made a server in node.js for my project, but localhost won't open.

The Server apparently works but when I enter http: // localhost: 8080 / the page is loading and does not open.

I am using express for the server.

I've been trying to solve it for hours but I can't find anything to solve it.

The project folder is \wsl$\Ubuntu\home\fplp\projects\Node-js-projects.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in Windos Subsystem for Linux

Next I will show the code of the server and a photo of the page of the terminal.

**//This is the server.js file\**

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function (req, res){
  res.render("index");
})

app.get("/about", function (req, res){
  res.render("about");
})

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is Online");
```

//Photo of terminal (wsl).

[Hyper terminal photo(wsl)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ikW2.jpg)

Comment: The image says server is active, what do you mean by not opening?

Comment: Is anything printed to the terminal when you attempt to connect, or does the connection just time out silently?

Perhaps try running a basic version (ex: simply `res.status(200).send("Hello!")` in your response function, and log connections, to remove possible causes of error.).

Comment: Gandalf, i use console.log to print a message on console when the server is online. But when i try to open localhost:8080, the page load and does not open.

Comment: John, i don't know if you saw the image, but I used console.log to see if the server is online.

And when I ran server.js the message appeared on the console, then the server is working, but the localhost: 8080 is loading and does not open.

Comment: I fix the problem, thanks for support!